# I can ping but Putty SSH says: server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh

I have a strange issue with a server (hosted in AWS). **I can ping from** the laptop of my office and it seems that I can also connect on port 22 with telnet like this:

```
$ telnet 10.151.127.4 22
```

output of telnet:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
```

But If i try to connect with Putty I recieve the following message as soon as I try to click Open:

> server unexpectedly closed network connection

Note: that other collegues located in other sites can connect to it.
Note2: I can ping to it
Note3: I need to connect from windows

PuttyLog:

```
2017-11-06 14:09:07 Looking up host "10.151.127.4"
2017-11-06 14:09:07 Connecting to 10.151.127.4 port 22
2017-11-06 14:09:07 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
2017-11-06 14:09:07 Using SSH protocol version 2
2017-11-06 14:09:07 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
2017-11-06 14:09:07 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2017-11-06 14:09:07 Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Comment: What does PuTTY's event log show?

Comment: @grawity: edited my post. I think the network is ok since putty is able to reach the server right ?

Comment: Does this still occur with the latest PuTTY version (0.70)?

Comment: Gosh! I updated to 0.7 and now works! You can write an answer for this I will accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client and server disagree on something about the *key exchange* process. Possibly the server has been excessively "hardened" and either requires stronger DH groups than the old PuTTY version can offer.

To know the exact details you'd have to enable debug logging on the *server* side, i.e on the end which cuts the connection first.

Either way, PuTTY 0.62 was released in 2011 – nearly six years ago. Since then it has received many updates (the latest version is 0.70), and recent versions are more likely to be accepted by your server.

More importantly, PuTTY 0.68 and later support ECDH, i.e. elliptic-curve key exchange, using both P-256 and X25519. This feature replaces traditional DH altogether, is somewhat faster and more secure, and in particular X25519 is likely to be included in even the strictest <del>copy&pasted</del> configurations.

Answer (score 0):

So as @grawity posted in the comments, I had an out-dated version of Putty.
I have updated it to 0.70 and now it works.

So if you can ping your machine and telnet connects to port 22 while putty fails, the answer is to update your putty.

Comment: "Update PuTTY" is a good second thing to try, but it's not automatically the answer... there can be some surprisingly obscure causes. (Hence why the _first_ thing is to look at the detailed log and pick out the part which fails.)